# A relation $R$ is defined on a set of real numbers $R$ as $R=\{(x,y):xy \text{ is irrational number}\}$. Check whether R is transitive.

Tags: relations

In the book they solve it by taking examples. Let x be this,y that,z and y those and they just put in condition. But all values do not give same result.

I took $x$, $y$, $z$ as $\sqrt 3$, $\sqrt 2$ and $4$. Let $(x,y),\ (y,z) \in R$, $xy\in R$ and $yz\in R$ that gives $xy= \sqrt 6$ and $yz=4\sqrt 2$. On solving for $x$ and $z$ from these equations and they multiplying $x$ and $z$, $xz= \sqrt 6$ which is irrational and $(x,z)\in R$ but in answer they solved it like
[image: Solution]

How different results from different values?

Comment: What's the definition of a transitive relation?

Comment: Either it is true or it is not. If it is not the easiest way to prove is by example. Note that $1\ R \sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2} R 1$ but it is not true that $1 R 1$.

Comment: To disprove something, you need to find a counterexample right? It may happen that there are tons of examples but that does not prove your statement.

Comment: You are asked to check if $R$ is transitive for $all$ numbers. Your examples shows that the transitivity property is verified for a certain triplet of numbers but your task is really to either show that it is verified for all triplets or to find a triplet for which it is not verified. I like the counterexample  $ (\Pi, 1, {1\over \Pi})$

Comment: Ok how to decide which examples to check

Comment: In questions they never say if it is transitive or not. They say to check. Sometimes it is Sometimes it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation R on a set X is transitive if, for all elements a, b, c in X, whenever R relates a to b and b to c, then R also relates a to c.

Note that,

if transitivity holds,it is true for $\textbf{all}$ elements a,b,c in X.

Here,in your example (x,z)$\in$ R but,in your book's example,and also in the example in 2nd comment, (x,z)$\notin$ R.

So, (x,z)$\in$ R does not hold for all x,y,z $\in$ R.

So R is not transitive.

Comment: Ok how do I know which example and which values to take

Comment: You have to check some examples definitely.But if R is transitive,then giving an example supporting to it ,is not sufficient. Because, according to definition,you have to check for all x,y,z.In this case,you have to prove it in general.But to disprove it,one counter example is sufficient.,i,e,you can say that,the condition is not true for all x,y,z, i,e, you have at least one pair not satisfiing the condition of transitivity.